# Unable to parse string with symbols with ANTLR 4

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I customised the simple expression grammar found in the "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" book. The new grammar is the following:

```
grammar Expr; 

prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE                    # printExpr
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE             # assign
    |   NEWLINE                         # blank
    ;

expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr          # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr          # AddSub
    |   INT                             # int
    |   ID                              # id
    |   '(' expr ')'                    # parens
    |   'min' '(' expr ',' expr ')'     # Min    
    |   'max' '(' expr ',' expr ')'     # Max
    |   'len' '(' string_constant ')'   # Len
    ;

MUL :   '*' ; // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar
DIV :   '/' ;
ADD :   '+' ;
SUB :   '-' ;
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace

string_constant :  '"' (ESC | ~('"' | '\\') )* '"' ;

ESC :   '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE) ;
fragment UNICODE : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX ;
fragment HEX : [0-9a-fA-F] ;
```

There is couple of new math functions (min and max) and string length.
Here there is the tree visitor that I used to parse:

```
public class EvalVisitor extends ExprBaseVisitor<Integer> 
{
    /** "memory" for our calculator; variable/value pairs go here */
    Map<String, Integer> memory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    /** ID '=' expr NEWLINE */
    @Override public Integer visitAssign(ExprParser.AssignContext ctx) 
    {
        String id = ctx.ID().getText();  // id is left-hand side of '='
        int value = visit(ctx.expr());   // compute value of expression on right
        memory.put(id, value);           // store it in our memory
        return value;
    }

    /** expr NEWLINE */
    @Override public Integer visitPrintExpr(ExprParser.PrintExprContext ctx) 
    {
        Integer value = visit(ctx.expr()); // evaluate the expr child
        System.out.println(value);         // print the result
        return 0;                          // return dummy value
    }

    /** INT */
    @Override public Integer visitInt(ExprParser.IntContext ctx) 
    { return Integer.valueOf(ctx.INT().getText()); }

    /** ID */
    @Override
    public Integer visitId(ExprParser.IdContext ctx) 
    {
        String id = ctx.ID().getText();
        if ( memory.containsKey(id) ) 
            return memory.get(id);
        return 0;
    }

    /** expr op=('*'|'/') expr */
    @Override public Integer visitMulDiv(ExprParser.MulDivContext ctx) 
    {
        int left = visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left subexpression
        int right = visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right subexpression
        if ( ctx.op.getType() == ExprParser.MUL ) 
            return left * right;
        return left / right; // must be DIV
    }

    /** expr op=('+'|'-') expr */
    @Override public Integer visitAddSub(ExprParser.AddSubContext ctx) 
    {
        int left = visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left subexpression
        int right = visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right subexpression
        if ( ctx.op.getType() == ExprParser.ADD ) 
            return left + right;
        return left - right; // must be SUB
    }

    /** '(' expr ')' */
    @Override
    public Integer visitParens(ExprParser.ParensContext ctx) 
    { return visit(ctx.expr()); }

    /** 'min' '(' expr ',' expr ')' */
    @Override public Integer visitMin(@NotNull ExprParser.MinContext ctx) 
    { 
        int left = visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left subexpression
        int right = visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right subexpression
        return Math.min(left,  right);
    }

    /** 'max' '(' expr ',' expr ')' */
    @Override public Integer visitMax(@NotNull ExprParser.MaxContext ctx) 
    { 
        int left = visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left subexpression
        int right = visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right subexpression
        return Math.max(left,  right);
    }

    /** 'len' '(' string_constant ')' */
    @Override public Integer visitLen(@NotNull ExprParser.LenContext ctx) 
    { 
        String str = ctx.string_constant().getText();
        return str.length()-2;
    }
}
```

The visitor can parse the expression:

```
   len("hello")
```

But is not able to parse the expression:

```
   len("hello%")
```

The message obtained is the following:

```
> java -jar Calc.jar 
len("hello")
len("hello%")
line 2:10 token recognition error at: '%'
5
5
```

Is there any error in the string_constant definition?

Regards
 Jona(than)

Answer (score 2):

`string_constant` should be a lexer rule instead:

```
STRING_CONSTANT
 :  '"' ( ESC | ~('"' | '\\') )* '"' 
 ;
```

and `ESC` a `fragment`:

```
fragment ESC : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE) ;
```

Comment: Thank you Bart, with the suggested change everything is working.